# How to GET ALL Data from Firebase Firestore document and filter the field

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So i have a Collection named "users" and document based on their authentication uid. I want to be able to go through ALL the users documents to find and display all the "full name" that have got a variable or field that is amphibianslvl3 > 80

[image: firebase]

How would i do this in flutter?

edit:
So far this is what I have

```
    class amphLeaderboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _amphLeaderboardState createState() => _amphLeaderboardState();
}

class _amphLeaderboardState extends State<amphLeaderboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(
      'Amphibians 100% Completion',
      style: GoogleFonts.sora(
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            /*fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,*/
            fontSize: 18,
            color: mywhite,
          )),
    ),
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    centerTitle: true,
    elevation: 0,
    ),
      body: Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .where("amphibianslvl3", isGreaterThan: 80)
            .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map(
                  (e) {
                return Text((e.data() as Map)["userName"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),);
              },
            ).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

but it is not returning anything, screen is just black

[image: amphibians level]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where("amphibianslvl3", isGreaterThan: 80).get();
```

Note: `amphibianslvl3` should not be missing in any user

To use it in a widget check this example:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .where("amphibianslvl3", isGreaterThan: 80)
          .get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
            (e) {
              return Text((e.data() as Map)["fulName"]);
            },
          ).toList(),
        );
      },
    )
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this, how would I display it in the page though? I want to display the full name for all the results that is amphibianslvl3>80

Comment: What would you like to show on the page?

Comment: I want to display the full name for all the results that is amphibianslvl3>80

Comment: Do you have to display them as items in a list?

Comment: preferably yes, but I just need to display all the document their "full name" that is amphibianslvl3>80, if that makes sense

Comment: I made an update with FutureBuilder, pease check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242302/discussion-between-laurentsai-and-josteve).

Comment: Hey, I've tried  it and edited my original post, here is what I have so far and the screen stay black, I'm trying to print the results on the screen. Hoping you can help.